# CKeditor returning 403 when submitting certain html tags

Tags: html, codeigniter, ckeditor, wysiwyg, http-status-code-403

I've created a page where I have two input textareas and I add CKeditor (ver. 4) to both of them.

The first editor works fine, I've set `config.allowedContent = true;` in the config.js to stop stripping tags like `<script>` and everything works as expected.
I have another editor right below it, same settings, same setup, I just changed the ID of the textarea field. It works when I submit normal text, but as soon as I add a `<script>` tag, for example, and press the submit button of the form in which the editors are in it seems to reload the page, doesn't submit any data and firebug tells me that the server returns 403.

I tried isolating the editor, adding personal configuration. Nothing. The first textarea works like a charm, second one returns 403 if the text has *unsafe* tags in it.

My setup is as follows, I'm using this [ckeditor helper](http://nukium.com/developpement/php-frameworks/codeigniter/ckeditor-helper-for-codeigniter/) to insert the editors where I need. Page is created with CodeIgniter as you guessed.
I got a config.js file in ckeditor folder.
I'm using a regular form, nothing fancy about it. It looks like this

```
<form action="http://domain.com/admin/articles/edit/47" method="post">
    <div id="cke_ckeditor_en_container">
        <textarea cols="75" rows="7" id="ckeditor_en" name="text_en" class="input-text is-col-text"><?php echo set_value('text_en', isset($text_en) ? htmlspecialchars_decode($text_en) : ''); ?></textarea>
        <?php echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor_en); ?>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The form has another part of html for the other editor which is the same, with changed id and other attributes, and a checkbox, nothing relevant.

And got this in my controller

```
public function edit(){
    $this->load->helper('ckeditor');
    $id = (int)$this->uri->segment(4);

    if (empty($id)){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Empty ID!');
        redirect('admin/articles');
    }

    $data = $this->articles_model->fetch_article($id);

    $data['page_title'] = "Edit `" . $data['title'] . "`";
    $data['form_url'] = "admin/articles/edit/" . $id;

    $data['ckeditor'] = array(
        'id'    =>  'ckeditor',
        'path'  =>  'js/ckeditor');
    $data['ckeditor_en'] = array(
        'id'    =>  'ckeditor_en',
        'path'  =>  'js/ckeditor');

    $data['edit'] = true;   

    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $this->save_article("update",$id);
    }


    $this->load->view("admin/articles",$data);
}

private function save_article($type='insert', $id=0){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title','trim|xss_clean|max_length[150]|min_length[1]');          
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text','Text','trim');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title_en','Title EN','trim|xss_clean|max_length[150]|min_length[1]');            
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text_en','Text EN','trim');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('top_menu','Show in top menu','trim|xss_clean|max_length[1]');            


    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // make sure we only pass in the fields we want

    $data = array();
    $data['title']       = $this->input->post('title');
    $data['text']        = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('text'));

    $data['title_en']       = $this->input->post('title_en');
    $data['text_en']        = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('text_en'));

    $data['url']               = $this->toAscii($this->input->post('title'));
    $data['url_en']            = $this->toAscii($this->input->post('title_en'));

    $data['top_menu']        = $this->input->post('top_menu');

    if($type == "insert"){
        $data['time']           = date("YmdHis");
    }


    if ($type == 'insert'){
        if($this->articles_model->insert($data)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Article added successfully!');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'An error occured!');
        }
    }else if ($type == 'update'){
        if($this->articles_model->update($id, $data)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Article `' . $data['title'] . '` edited successfully!');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'An error ecc!');
        }
    }
    redirect("admin/articles");

}
```

*Safety, or unsafeness, to be exact, of my code is not relevant*

**edit**
Adding `config.js` for ckeditor.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/js/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/js/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/js/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/js/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/js/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/js/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';

    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
    config.allowedContent = true;
    // Se the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Make dialogs simpler.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

I'm stumped and stupified, I've got **no** ideas on what to do. It seems that the one input has been cursed.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you post the all of the relevant controller and view code? Are you using `ckeditor_en` for both textareas?

Comment: The ID's are unique, I don't think it would even work with repeating ones. I will post the code in a second.

Comment: So to be clear: the first editor works correctly with disallowed text (e.g. `<script>`) and the second does not? 403 is a [forbidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) error. Can you inspect the network requests (developer tools/firebug) and see which is throwing the error?

Comment: Well, CKeditor 4 removes these tags by default so I set it not to in the config.js file (I will add it to my original post as well). The first editor works as expected - content is saved and displayed correctly, the second editor with the same settings and setup, however, does not and returns said error. I isolated the second editor and made sure that it was the source of the problem by submitting content without *unsafe* tags which works fine, and doing it again with them, which returns the 403 error.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network Figuring out what request is causing the 403 will be important.

Comment: Hope this helps - http://imgur.com/8nxbIix

Comment: Kind of hard to tell without seeing the URL path; it's possible there are disallowed characters being added to the url or something. Can you compare that request to the request that's made for the first textfield?

Comment: Well there is a single request made if both editors are on and it doesn't change if I turn either of the editors off. I mean, they both are in a same form, one above other, submitting to the same url. Oh, and the url is `domain.com/admin/articles/edit/<ID OF ARTICLE>` just as I've stated in my post.

Comment: How is your server configured? IIRC, Apache `mod_security`, and probably many other similar such tools, will throw a 403 if it sees something it really doesn't like, potentially such as `<script>` tags in POST content. A quick first-line test would be to disable ckEditor entirely, and see whether you get the same result submitting through a bare textarea; if so, you know ckEditor's not at fault, and it's time to start looking at your server configuration.

Comment: I just downloaded and tested on a local install of CI 2.1.3 with your config.js, the helper, and your view (used the controller from the helper tutorial); no problems here. @Aaron Miller probably is on the right track. And I was asking what the URL of the request was that returned the 403, not the form action URL.

Comment: Mod_security! I've more or less only read about it and turns out that **was** the thing that caused the trouble.  I'm still confused on why it wasn't triggered for the first input. I asked my host to check whether it was the problem and they confirmed it. Thank you so much, both sotrmdrain and Aaron, for your time and patience! If you would post your comment as an answer I could accept it.

Comment: In my case, I only encountered this issue with a combination of text in bold and font forecolor; either one of them on their own was fine. As noted by @AaronMiller and Pankucins, my hosting site needed to change mod_security to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the result of your mod_security rules. Depending on how strict they are they help better protect scripts from being hacked through vulnerabilities, generally those exploited via POST's.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to add something to your second textarea. And CKEditor removing some "unsafe" tags. I won't be very secure, but this can help you:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = '*{*}';
```

You will add this to your config.js. This code provides you to add anything you want. And CKEditor won't delete "unsafe" tags.

[Documenation for this method](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.bilisimkitabi.com/403-error-on-submit-of-ckeditor
You can add to following code in your .htaccess file

```
#ckeditor Post 403 problem
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
#ckeditor Post 403 problem
```